# RMI: Are there still _stub files generated?

Tags: java, rmi, stub

I know skeletons are outdated and not used any more. Stubs are still used though, but are there still _stub classes generated? If yes where can I see these classes (Iam working with Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're generated if *you* generate them with the `rmic` tool. No magic. The stub is generated in the same package as the remote object it is a stub for.

Comment: Nowadays stubs are generated dynamically, so you don't have to do it yourself anymore with the _rmic_ command. But even dynamically there's still _stub files generated, you just don't have to do it yourself?